# Valid nested loop in Java is not valid in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Following expression is valid in Java. Btw, I am also using Apache Commons Math

```
RealMatrix coefficients =
    new Array2DRowRealMatrix(new double[][] { { 2, 3, -2 }, { -1, 7, 6 }, { 4, -3, -5 } }, false);
```

But `new double[][] { { 2, 3, -2 }, { -1, 7, 6 }, { 4, -3, -5 } }` is invalid in Groovy. Why? And how it can be rewritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this

```
coefficients = [[2.0, 3.0, -2.0],[ -1.0, 7.0, 6.0 ],[ 4.0, -3.0, -5.0 ]] as double[][]
```

Comment: you should add "as double[][]" to the end of this. otherwise it will be a List, not an array.